# Como eu posso capturar os name de um formulario html e colocar em uma variavel no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu sei como fazer com PhP mas to apanhando um pouquinho com javascript, queria usar os campos "nome" e "email" para colocar o que o usuario digitar dentro de uma variavel nome e outra email dentro do JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar:

- `.querySelector('input[name="nome"]').value`
- `.getElementsByName('nome')[0].value`
- ou usar *id* (`#`) ou *class* (`.`) e seletores:

  - `document.getElementById('id').value`
  - `document.getElementByClassName('classe')[0].value`
  - `document.querySelectorAll('.classe')[0].value`

Repara que se usares `getElementsByName` ou `querySelectorAll`, ou getElementsByClassName`isso vi dar uma coleção e não podes usar`.value`diretamente, tens de usar`[0]` se quiseres o primeiro elemento da coleção, etc...

#### Exemplo:

```js
var nome = document.querySelector('input[name="nome"]');
var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]');

nome.value = 'Bianca San';
email.value = 'bianca.san@dominio.algo';
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input name="nome" />
<input name="email" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, se você deseja capturar o atributo name da tag input, ficaria assim :

```
 var campo = document.querySelector("input:nth-child(1)");
 var nameCampo = campo.getAttribute("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, é simples:

```
var nome = document.getElementByName('nome_do_input').value;
```

Comment: muito obrigada :)

Comment: Faltou o "s"...

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` dá uma coleção por isso `document.getElementsByName('nome_do_input').value` não vai funcionar.